# what is the difference between multi-lingual heteroglossia and translational polyglossia?

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of this particular sentence considering the difference between multi-lingual heteroglossia and translational polyglossia.

*Looking forward to the next section, we might ask whether one ought to classify Henry Roth’s intricately layered 1934 novel Call It Sleep as multi-lingual, mono-lingual heteroglossia, or translational polyglossia.*

Comment: I suggest you look forward to the next section and see if the author has explained his idiosyncratic terms.

Comment: One has lots of types of a language, the other has lots of different languages. This is general reference.

Comment: @JonHanna which is which?

Comment: @Mitch, ... respectively ....

Comment: @JonHanna Oh, because I would have thought the other way, from the way you said it. multi-lingual means to me having many languages (not many types of a single language) and mono-lingual heteroglossia means a single language of ... heteroglossia? different somethings? The latter doesn't settle to one meaning for me.

Comment: Oh. I've misunderstood. Is it "multilingual monolingual heteroglossia" and "translational polyglossia"? If so how can hetero glossia be both multilingual and monolingual at the same time?

Comment: @Mitch that is exactly my question.

Comment: @Colin: I can read some of the book the sentence comes from online, and unless I'm missing something, the author never actually explains the way *Call it Sleep* is written. Which means the sentence remains opaque unless the reader actually does some research to learn something about *Call it Sleep*. What he says is the offhand remark *"or creating distinct forms of English to represent different languages – as Henry Roth does in Call It Sleep."*

Comment: In which case it is a piece of bad writing appropriate to _Pseuds Corner_.

Answer (score 2):

*Call it Sleep* is written entirely in English, but the dialog that is supposed to be spoken in Yiddish is in grammatical English, while the dialog that is supposed to be spoken in English is in very broken, Yiddish-influenced English (at least, the dialog spoken by recent Jewish immigrants from Eastern Europe, which if I recall correctly is the majority of the dialog).

So *multilingual* because they are speaking two different languages, and *monolingual* because everything is actually written in English; *polyglossia* because they are speaking two different languages, *heteroglossia* because the novel is written in different varieties of English, and *translational* because Yiddish is translated to English.

I doubt that the meaning of the sentence can be deduced without first knowing that *Call it Sleep* is actually multilingual polyglossia textually represented by translation into monolingual heteroglossia.

Comment: Indeed. Now that you've explained about the book (which I've never heard of), I can see how the terms might be applicable. But I concur with your last paragraph.